# comparing number of table entries with a maximum number

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve an integer table element (max) which is 3 or 4 depending on the course, and comparing that with the number of elements already entered into the table.

Here is the code I am using to get the course maximum enrolment and the total number of courses registered:

```
//Store the value of the course enrolment limit
$course1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['coursename']);
$qw2 = "SELECT max FROM course WHERE name = '$course1'";
$courselimit = mysql_query($qw2) or die (mysql_error());


//check how many students are enrolled in the course
$qw3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enrolled WHERE course = '$course1' LIMIT 4";
$totalenrolled = mysql_query($qw3) or die (mysql_error());
```

Unfortunately my if statement does not seem to be working as it registers as true even when the number of table entries has exceeded the course limit.

```
    if ($totalenrolled >= $courselimit ){
        die('That course has reached the enrolment limit, please select another');
    }
```

EDIT1: Here is the dump for the course table, I have tried Alexey's solution, but unfortunately the statement does not appear to be functioning yet. I have isolated the problem to the $courselimit variable

```
--
-- Table structure for table `course`
--

CREATE TABLE `course` (
`name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`max` int(2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `course`
--

INSERT INTO `course` (`name`, `code`, `max`) VALUES
('HTML', 'PROG-1288', 4),
('Javascript', 'PROG-2283', 3),
('Dreamweaver', 'MEDA-1380', 4),
('Photoshop', 'PHOT-1382', 3);
```

and here is the dump for the table I am inserting the values into and attempting to read from:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `enrolled`
--

CREATE TABLE `enrolled` (
`student` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`studentnum` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`course` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
FULLTEXT KEY `student` (`student`,`studentnum`,`course`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `enrolled`
--

INSERT INTO `enrolled` (`student`, `studentnum`, `course`) VALUES
('graham', '987654', 'HTML'),
('bruce', '123456', 'HTML'),
('jane', '111222', 'HTML');
```

Comment: you are comparing the queried objects not the data from these objects first fetch results then compare them

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [mysql_num_rows](https://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows)().

```
//Store the value of the course enrolment limit
$course1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['coursename']);
$qw2 = "SELECT max as `maxitem` FROM course WHERE name = '$course1'";
$res = mysql_query($qw2) or die (mysql_error());
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$courselimit = $result['maxitem'];


//check how many students are enrolled in the course
$qw3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enrolled WHERE course = '$course1'";
$res = mysql_query($qw3) or die (mysql_error());
$totalenrolled = mysql_num_rows($res);
```

Comment: So the mysql_num_rows function worked for $totalenrolled, but $courselimit is still only returning 1 even when there is more than one element in the table column. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide dump for `course` and answer what is `max` on this table?

Comment: I changed the code to the edit's you have made, but each variable is still only returning 1. I have also provided the dump for the 'enrolled' table

Answer (score 0):

Have you echoed the values `$totalenrolled` and `$courselimit` and checked it against the data in your data table to ensure you're getting what you want?

Also, the `LIMIT 4` in the `$qw3` won't be doing anything--there would only be one result since you're using `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, forget using `mysql`, instead, prefer `mysqli_` or `PDO` for all operations, its more robust and secure!

[**You can get basic understanding of `mysqli_` from here**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Now, **Problem :**

Under `if` condition, you are comparting on `objects` when you have to do that on `value` :

**Solution**

fetch the values, before comparing them :

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($courselimit,MYSQLI_ASSOC); /* associative array */
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($totalenrolled,MYSQLI_ASSOC); /* associative array */
```

then compare them

```
if ($row['max'] >= $row2['count'] ) //assuming count is column name for 2nd resukt
```

Comment: Please don't mix `mysqli_` and `mysql_`. They won't work together.

Comment: @h2ooooooo : patience is the virtue mate, i was updating answer, mentioning that OP shouldn't use `mysql`, and gave my answer in line of `mysqli_`.... :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching the Mysql Object. Try this one will works I hope.

```
//Store the value of the course enrolment limit
$course1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['coursename']);
$qw2 = "SELECT  COUNT(*) as count1 FROM course WHERE name = '$course1'";
$courselimit = mysql_fetch_assoc((mysql_query($qw2)) or die (mysql_error());


//check how many students are enrolled in the course
$qw3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count2 FROM enrolled WHERE course = '$course1' LIMIT 4";
$totalenrolled = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($qw3)) or die (mysql_error());


 if ($totalenrolled['count2'] >= $courselimit['count1 '] ){
    die('That course has reached the enrolment limit, please select another');
}
```

Comment: in era of `mysqli_`, suggesting `mysql` is sin now...a coder should know that!! :D